# Including/Importing aliases and functions for both bash and zsh

Tags: bash, import, function, include, zsh

I have a directory of functions and aliases I'd like to include for both bash and zsh terminal invocations (So I don't need to put every function and alias into every separate script and to facilitate organization/tidying of .rc files)

What I've tried so far hasn't worked. Just setting this out for further suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

For zsh I'm using

```
if [ -d ~/.zsh.d ]; then
    for i in ~/.zsh.d/*.sh; do
        if [ -r $i ]; then
            . $i
        fi
    done
    unset i
fi
```

Should work for bash, too.